# Add URL link in CSS background image - @media only screen

Tags: html, css

I have a flexible newsletter - 3 steps:

bigger than > 660 px

smaller < 600 px

smaller < 350 px

everything works excluding link on images 
I have a CSS entry that looks like this:

http://mantykora.cleoni.com/~newsletter/2017/lak/Lak_EN.htm

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 660px) {
        table.container { width: 600px !important; }

        td.logo img { display:none; }
        td.logo { background:#fff url(http://mantykora.cleoni.com/~newsletter/2017/lak/images/logo65.jpg) no-repeat 10px 10px; height: 60px;}
        td.logo a {??????????????link to site???????????}
```

is it possible linking image on media screnn?

Comment: href is html object attribute, not css style

Answer (score 0):

Use two elements, one to be shown on narrow viewports and one to be shown on wide viewports.

CSS:

```
.only-narrow { display: block; }
.only-wide { display: none; }
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .only-narrow { display: none; }
  .only-wide { display: block; }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="only-narrow" ><a href="..." ><img src="..." ></a></div>
<div class="only-wide" ><img src="..." ></div>
```